# Inserting Images into Django Template

Tags: python, django

I understand that there are many existing questions about Django template images, but I just can't seem to get mine to work. I currently have an app within my project and have a static folder structure that looks like

```
    djangoproject/appname/static/images/
```

In the templates folder of the same django app, I have a variety of HTML files that need to reference the images in the folder shown above. In my `settings.py` folder, I have

```
    STATIC_ROOT=''
    STATIC_URL = 'appname/static/' 
    STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    ) 
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

)

In my template file, I have

```
    <a href="AddTransaction.html"><img id="btnTransaction" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/btnTransaction.png"/></a>
```

When I run the dev server, it keeps looking at `appname/images/btnTransaction.png` for the image.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of appname and change to `STATIC_URL= '/static/'`

Answer (score 1):

In the `STATIC_FILES_DIR` tuple, you need to have a string that is the **absolute path** to the static directory on your machine. So if you're *nix it would be `'/User/path/to/django/static/dir/'` or `'C:/path/to/django/static/dir/'` if you're on Windows.

`STATIC_URL`, like you see here, is whatever will be output in the HTML and is meant for the **absolute path** of an image relative to the browser. You could do `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/'` if you're running locally or something like `'http://mydomain.com/static/'` if in production or something like  `'http://static.mydomain.com/static/'` if you have a CDN or just `'/static/'` to work for all (if you're using the same host for your static files and app).

Comment: I appreciate the help. However, I did what you said to do, and yet it still doesn't work. I'm really confused as to why no matter what I do, the server keeps looking at the same url for the images, which is obviously not correct. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you want the path to the images to be in a *web* accessible location, something away from django and your app (unless you're adding access controls, then you'll need a separate function in your views to handle that).  Thing is, the img tag's src is not pulling the image in when the template is rendered server side, but in the client and the client makes a separate request for the image. If the image can't be found by the url, then it won't get shown.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "static" use "media"

like so

settings.py

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/YOUR USERNAME/djcode/blankpage/media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in urls.py

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':  settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

in your template reference your file like this

```
href="/media/styles/profile.css"
```